# On AKS are System node pool the same as master node?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I know that with Azure AKS , master components are fully managed by the service. But I'm a little confused here when it comes to pick the node pools. I understand that there are two kind of pools system and user, where the user nodes pool offer hosting my application pods. I read on official documentation that **System node pools serve the primary purpose of hosting critical system pods such as CoreDNS and tunnelfront.** And i'm aware that we can only rely on system nodes to create and run our kubernetes cluster.

My question here, do they mean here by the system node the **MASTER node** ? If it is so, why then we have the option to not create the user nodes (worker node by analogy) ? because as we know -in on prem kubernetes solution- we cannot create a kubernetes cluster with master nodes only.

[image]

I'll appreciate any help

Comment: Maybe you can share the link to what you said "official documentation" there?

Answer (score 4):

System node pools in AKS does not contain Master nodes. Master nodes in AKS are 100% managed by Azure and are outside your VNet. A system node pool contains worker nodes on which AKS automatically assigns the label `kubernetes.azure.com/mode: system`, that's about it. AKS then use that label to deploy critical pod like `tunnelfront`, which is use to create a secure communication from your nodes to the control plane. You need at least 1 system node pool per cluster and they have the [following restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools#system-and-user-node-pools) :

- System pools osType must be Linux.
- System pools must contain at least one node, and user node pools may contain zero or more nodes.
- System node pools require a VM SKU of at least 2 vCPUs and 4GB memory. But burstable-VM(B series) is not recommended.
- System node pools must support at least 30 pods as described by the minimum and maximum value formula for pods.